# JavaScript DOM and JQuery Event differences

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two set of code one is from JavaScript and JQuery.

JavaScript - here I am traversing through my html code and adding an event listener and passing the value down to my function to compare using a switch. So when I clicked on a button this produces a sound and works fine but in JQuery it doesn't work the same way and I don't understand why.

```
for(var i=0;i < arrayLength; i++){
      document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function(){

      var buttonInnerHTML = this.innerHTML;
      makeSound(buttonInnerHTML);
      buttonAnimation(buttonInnerHTML);
  });
}

function makeSound(key){  
  switch (key) {
    case "w":
      var tom1 = new Audio('sounds/tom-1.mp3');
      tom1.play();
      break;
    case "a":
      var tom2 = new Audio("sounds/tom-2.mp3");
      tom2.play();
      break;
    case "s":
      var tom3 = new Audio("sounds/tom-3.mp3");
      tom3.play();
      break;
    case "d":
      var tom4 = new Audio("sounds/tom-4.mp3");
      tom4.play();
      break;
    case "j":
      var snare = new Audio("sounds/snare.mp3");
      snare.play();
      break;
    case "k":
      var crash = new Audio("sounds/crash.mp3");
      crash.play();
      break;
    case "l":
      var kick = new Audio("sounds/kick-bass.mp3");
      kick.play();
      break;
    default:
      //console.log(buttonInnerHTML);
  }
}
```

In JQuery I did the exact same thing but instead of playing the animation one time, the animation is played by the amount of times my forloop looped. In my case it was 4 times.

```
for(var i=0; i < numOfButtons; i++){
    $(".btn").on("click",function(){
    var buttonPress = $(".btn").index(this); //getting index value of array clicked
    //var buttonPress = $(this).text(); //getting text

    //console.log(buttonPress);
    buttonSelect(buttonPress);
  })
}

function buttonSelect(key){

  switch (key) {
    case 0:
    console.log("hi");
      $("#green").fadeOut();
      $("#green").fadeIn();
      break;
    case 1:
      $("#red").fadeOut();
      $("#red").fadeIn();
      break;
    case 2:
      $("#yellow").fadeOut();
      $("#yellow").fadeIn();
      break;
    case 3:
      $("#blue").fadeOut();
      $("#blue").fadeIn();
        break;

    default:

  }
}
```

So I realised there's a difference between JQuery's event listener vs JavaScript because when I took out the forloop for the JQuery everything worked normally as it should. if I click on something it plays it one time instead of forlooping.

```
 $(".btn").on("click",function(){
    var buttonPress = $(".btn").index(this); //getting index value of array clicked
    //var buttonPress = $(this).text(); //getting text

    //console.log(buttonPress);
    buttonSelect(buttonPress);
  });

function buttonSelect(key){

  switch (key) {
    case 0:
    console.log("hi");
      $("#green").fadeOut();
      $("#green").fadeIn();
      break;
    case 1:
      $("#red").fadeOut();
      $("#red").fadeIn();
      break;
    case 2:
      $("#yellow").fadeOut();
      $("#yellow").fadeIn();
      break;
    case 3:
      $("#blue").fadeOut();
      $("#blue").fadeIn();
        break;

    default:
  }
}
```

I want to understand the difference as to why JQuery loops 4 times when I have a forloop as to the Dom Javascript which does not.

Comment: Every time `$(".btn").on()` is called, it adds another copy of the event handler to **all** the buttons.

Comment: So it attaches an event handler to all the buttons but what about the JavaScript DOM event handler does that attaches event handler individually to each button?

Comment: In your vanilla JS script you loop through the buttons and add a listener to each one, so it's ok. With jQuery, `$(".btn")` already selects all the buttons and you can add the listener to all of them at the same time, so you don't need the loop.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: One question so addEventListener with JavaScript cannot add directly to all of the buttons but have to go through them one by one correct? e.g.  "document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener" would work using loop but  document.querySelectorAll(".drum").addEventListener - wont work.